# I can't compile a .cpp file in VSCode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

It's my fisrt time to use VSCode. I wrote a .cpp file, and pressed the 'Debug C/C++ File' button. But it showed me
The preLaunchTask 'C/C++: gcc.exe build active file' terminated with exit code -1.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzdP0.png)
And I pressed the 'Debug Anyway', then it showed that the .exe file doesn't exist. I opened the launch.json and tasks.json, they are like this:

launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": []
}
```

tasks.json

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "D:\\environment\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

I have already installed the gcc and g++ on my device. And I don't know how to fix it.

I've tried to delete the .vscode which has been installed automatically, and then debugged again. But still doesn't work. I've read some blogs, some suggested to make some adjustments on the launch.json and tasks.json, but I don't know how to adjust them.

Comment: Advice: [Follow the instructions to the letter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) to get started. When you gain familiarity, then start freestylin'.

Comment: I think the first step you be to forget about VSCode and instead try to compile from the command line What happens if you try that? VSCode cannot compile if your compiler g++ is not working correctly.

Comment: You are programming on Windows, why not use Visual Studio Community Edition instead. It is free, easier and better than VSCode. VSCode is too complicated for beginners.

Comment: I hope to use the leetcode extension, so I chose the VSCode.

Comment: Also looking at your task.json file you are using the wrong compiler for C++, `g++` not `gcc`. As already mentioned, don't try to figure out VSCode, follow the instructions.

Comment: @Shawn Interesting, that might explain a lot. Of course leetcode is no way to learn C++ programming (assuming that is your aim).

Comment: I use the g++/gcc --version in my command window, and both exist. So I think maybe there is no error in g++ and gcc.

Comment: I switched the gcc and g++, both didn't work.

Comment: @Shawn Existence is not enough, try to reproduce the actual command that VSCode would use to build your program, something like `D:\environment\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe -g program.cpp -o program.exe`

Comment: @Shawn In any case what you should really do is start again, and this time follow the documentation.

Comment: Please show the compiler output, that'll tell you why the code isn't compiling

Comment: @john I believe `g++` is indeed the normal way to call the GNU C++ compiler, at least on Unices. Using `gcc` in place of `g++` for C++ can work, but the lack of C++ stdlib headers in `gcc`'s default include path can be a source of trouble.

Comment: @mcendu in general using gcc for compiling c++ code doesn't cause any problems, it detects the language from the file extension and correctly compiles it as c++ code. What it doesn't do is link to libstdc++ so the linker will fail

Comment: @AlanBirtles Oh yep, got that detail wrong